# How to use if statement inside React JSX loop/map

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to output two different versions of some HTML inside a React component based on an if statment, this is how I think it should look but the syntax is not right. I am trying to add "active" Breadcrumb.Item if the value of breadCrumbLink.IsActive is true.

```
{breadCrumbData.BreadCrumbLinks.map(breadCrumbLink => (

if (breadCrumbLink.IsActive == true)
{
    <Breadcrumb.Item key={breadCrumbLink.Id} className="active">
        {breadCrumbLink.LinkText}
    </Breadcrumb.Item active>

}
else
{
    <Breadcrumb.Item key={breadCrumbLink.Id} className="active">
        {breadCrumbLink.LinkText}
    </Breadcrumb.Item>
}

))}
```

Comment: That's not actually a JSX problem, although it's from the same limitation - an arrow function without a block body, _like_ a JSX interpolation, can only have a single expression. In this case, as you're _not_ in the JSX case, why not _introduce a block body_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to render conditionally. Use the condition inside the active property (and inside className if you need):

```
{breadCrumbData.BreadCrumbLinks.map(breadCrumbLink => 
    (
        <Breadcrumb.Item key={breadCrumbLink.Id} className="active" active={breadCrumbLink.IsActive}>
            {breadCrumbLink.LinkText}
        </Breadcrumb.Item>
    )
)}
```

Comment: I didn't know that 
<Breadcrumb.Item active> was the same as <Breadcrumb.Item active="true">
I didn't know that it was a prop - Thank you Igor.